# How to create custom notification in Flutter like in a music player and handle button clicks

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create custom notification in Flutter like in a music player and handle button clicks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package called **[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)**.
that provides most of the type of notification please check.

It works with android as well as IOS.

Here is the Example [link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example)

Thanks