# Create custom layout for notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, custom-notification

I need any example to create a custom layout for notification and link that to my flutter app for firebase push notification.
Anyone have any knowledge on it please help me. Thank you.

I need this type of notification for my App firebase push notifictaion.

[image]

Comment: refer here:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/example

Comment: https://flutterawesome.com/tag/notification/

Comment: @gretal is the same design is possible with flutter_local_notifications package ?

Comment: yeah, it is possible. Try it once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom notification in Flutter like in a music player and handle button clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711616/how-to-create-custom-notification-in-flutter-like-in-a-music-player-and-handle-b)

Comment: did you find an answer for this ? @gretal  solution provided won't work as there isn't any customisable option for notification in flutter , notifications can only be customised through layouts written in xml

Comment: Found this invoking native android method sample for custom notification : https://github.com/imamhossain94/flutter-custom-notification